# How to properly finish a Branched Survey on Sharepoint?

Tags: survey-list, survey

I am sorry if this is a very dumb question, but I just don't know how to solve it.

I am doing a Survey that has branched questions. Is a rather complex survey, it has many questions. But I will simplify my example.

My first question has 3 options:

- Option 1=> It branches to more questions, that has more branches.
- Option 2=> It jumps to another question (Q2) and it should end there.
- Option 3=> It jumps to another question (Q3) and it should end there.

My problem is in any case I have a final question like Q2 and then it should **end**.
Unless i do a branch from Q2 to "content type" (which I don't know what it is, and why is showing in the list of questions) when Sharepoint shows the Q2 question, it shows all other questions I have created after Q2.

How can I make a Question to be a final Question?

What is the "content type" item?

Comment: The `Content Type` item is a system field holding the item's content type. It's managed by the system and shall not be edited by the user. The last question shall be the last one in the quetionnaire. SharePoint's built-in survey capabilities are rather limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Cannot make a Question final. Just add a dummy question like, "Did you enjoyed this survey
"? or "Any Suggestions"?